# A Scrum Master is working with a Development Team that has members in different physical locations

Tags: scrum, scrum-master, daily-scrum, scrum-team

I had a question during PSM1 assessment:

> A Scrum Master is working with a Development Team that has members in different physical locations. The Development Team meets in a variety of meeting rooms arid has much to do logistically (for example, set up conference calls) before the Daily Scrum. What action should the Scrum Master take?

- Allow the Development Team to self-manage and determine for itself what to-do.
- Set up the meeting and tell the Development Team that is how it will be done.
- Ask the Development Team members to alternate who is responsible for meeting setup.
- inform management and ask them to solve it.

Can anyone suggest me proper answer out of given options?

My choice is: `inform management and ask them to solve it.` - As per my knowledge Scrum Master is responsible for resolution to any impediments to the development team. 
But as per scrum development team is self-organizing team so other possible answer can be `Allow the Development Team to self-manage and determine for itself what to-do.`

Not sure I'm correct.

Comment: You have quite a few of these up and I read your comment on another that this is the only place you know that you can get help on these. I think that is fair that we can help, but you might get a warmer reception and better responses if you share what your thoughts are (maybe what answer you think you'd pick and why) and share why you find the question difficult to answer. Please also understand that most of us do not know what Scrum.org considers the right answer (some of their questions are purposefully tricky) and you can't take any suggestions as more than just suggestions.

Comment: the correct answer is : **Allow the Development Team to self-manage and determine for itself what to-do.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Let Servant-Leadership Be Your Guide

The only possible answer of the four is:

> Allow the Development Team to self-manage and determine for itself what to-do.

The other options are all directive and presumptive in nature. Based on the description, it's not even clear that there's an actual problem from the team's perspective, nor that there's a process issue that would justify the Scrum Master role taking direct action.

Answer (score 2):

Here is possibility of both answers:

> inform management and ask them to solve it.

[Scrum Master Service to the Development Team according to Scrum Guide:](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#team-dev)
The Scrum Master serves the Development Team in several ways, including:

- Coaching the Development Team in self-organization and cross-functionality;
- Helping the Development Team to create high-value products;

  > - Removing impediments to the Development Team’s progress;
- Facilitating Scrum events as requested or needed; and,
- Coaching the Development Team in organizational environments in which Scrum is not yet fully adopted and understood.

It will be the Scrum Master's responsibility to remove impediments with the help of management.

---

[Possibility of Second Answer as per Scrum Guide](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#team-dev)

> Allow the Development Team to self-manage and determine for itself what to-do.

*Development Teams are structured and empowered by the organization to organize and manage their own work. The resulting synergy optimizes the Development Team’s overall efficiency and effectiveness.*